# MySQL Left Join - how to get count of records found in 2nd table

Tags: mysql

```
Table1

id    Name

1     John

2     Sheldon

3     Sarah
```

========

```
Table2

rid   id  id2  relation

1     1    2    1

2     1    3    1
```

How can i get all members from table 1 in one query and each member's total relations.

The result I want should be:

```
Jhon       2

Sheldon    0

Sarah      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.id2), 0)
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: Is IFNULL necessary? It gives same result when I replace IFNULL(COUNT(t2.id2), 0) with COUNT(t2.id2)?

Answer (score 3):

```
select Table1.name, count(Table2.id) from Table1 LEFT Join Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id group by Table2.id

    OR 

select Table1.name,IFNULL(count(Table2.id), 0) from Table1  LEFT Join Table2  on Table1.id=Table2.id group by Table2.id
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation Dude...!! it was helpful for me..!!